# How to select bottom N rows from each group - Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table as follows:

```
+-----------------+----------+-------------+-------------+
| QCD_OUTLET_CODE | QCD_YEAR | QCD_QUARTER | QCD_CREDITS |
+-----------------+----------+-------------+-------------+
|       144034911 |     2015 | Q2          | 269.5       |
|        10500106 |     2015 | Q2          | 303.35      |
|       144034911 |     2015 | Q1          | 231.85      |
|        10500106 |     2015 | Q1          | 250.4       |
|        10500106 |     2014 | Q4          | 276.5       |
|       144034911 |     2014 | Q4          | 224.5       |
+-----------------+----------+-------------+-------------+
```

I need to display bottom 2 rows ordered by `QCD_YEAR` and `QCD_QUARTER` such that the latest quarter has the last rank (displayed as last row for each group)
Previously, when there was only `2014/Q4` and `2015/Q1` (i.e., two records for per `QCD_OUTLET_CODE`), the following query worked fine to display the records in the order I wish:

```
WITH ordered 
     AS (SELECT qcd_outlet_code, 
                qcd_year, 
                qcd_quarter, 
                qcd_credit, 
                Row_number() 
                  over ( 
                    PARTITION BY qcd_outlet_code 
                    ORDER BY qcd_outlet_code, qcd_year, qcd_quarter) 
                AS rn 
         FROM   QTR_CREDIT_DATA) 
SELECT d.qcd_outlet_code    AS "Outlet_Code:string", 
       d.qcd_quarter 
       ||' ' 
       ||d.qcd_year         AS "MCT_quarter:string", 
       Nvl(d.qcd_credit, 0) AS "MCT_Total_Credits_Earned", 
       d.rn                 AS "Display_Order:string" 
FROM   ordered d 
WHERE  rn <= 2;
```

The result for two rows for per `QCD_OUTLET_CODE`:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------------+----------------------+
| Outlet_Code:string | MCT_quarter:string | MCT_Total_Crecits_Earned | Display_Order:string |
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------------+----------------------+
|           10500106 | Q4 2014            | 387                      |                    1 |
|           10500106 | Q1 2015            | 482.75                   |                    2 |
|          144034911 | Q4 2014            | 269.5                    |                    1 |
|          144034911 | Q1 2015            | 276.5                    |                    2 |
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------------+----------------------+
```

*Please ignore the numbers of QCD_QUARTER, they are arbitrary.*

So `Display_Order:string` will display 1 and 2. 
However, with additional row for each `QCD_OUTLET_CODE` I need also to show the bottom 2 rows per group (i.e., `2015/Q1` and `2015/Q2`) and I need them the have the values 1 and 2 for `Display_Order:string`

Running the same script above will return the same result above (`2014/Q4` and `2015/Q1`). 
If I use `DESC` in `Partition` clause, it will return the rows I want, but `Display_Order:string` will not have a correct value (`2015/Q2' will be give 1 instead of 2).

The result I wish from the first data set I posted above as follows:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------------+----------------------+
| Outlet_Code:string | MCT_quarter:string | MCT_Total_Crecits_Earned | Display_Order:string |
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------------+----------------------+
|           10500106 | Q1 2015            | 387                      |                    1 |
|           10500106 | Q2 2015            | 482.75                   |                    2 |
|          144034911 | Q1 2015            | 269.5                    |                    1 |
|          144034911 | Q2 2015            | 276.5                    |                    2 |
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------------+----------------------+
```

For its worth, the logic I'm trying to implement is like a window that slides over each group to display the latest two quarters, and give rows numbers accordingly.

Comment: Use `DESC` in `Row_number()  over ( PARTITION BY qcd_outlet_code ORDER BY qcd_outlet_code, qcd_year DESC, qcd_quarter DESC)` ;).

Comment: @shA.t That is a super fast answer. If you mean what I mentioned my question (partition order by desc), it did not return the correct the row_number I want. It gives 1 to the latest quarter, while I want it to give 2 to the latest, 1 to the first

Comment: @Hawk Put the `DESC` in `ORDER BY` clause not partition by and let us know the output. Remember, an **ORDER** is guaranteed ONLY when ORDER BY is specified. To get reverse order, you must use DESC.

Comment: @LalitKumarB `DESC` in `FROM  QTR_CREDIT_DATA  ORDER BY qcd_year desc, qcd_quarter desc` will not return the last quarter (only q4/2014 and q1/2015 returned). `DESC` in `PARTITION BY qcd_outlet_code  ORDER BY qcd_outlet_code, qcd_year DESC, qcd_quarter DESC` will return the last quarter q2/2015, but the order will be 1 instead of 2. (q2/2015) is displayed at the top).

Comment: Then use just `CASE WHEN order = 1 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END` to switch 1 with 2 and 2 with 1

Comment: @kordirko They are so many quarters, I'm using sample data here. Besides, data is dynamic and quarters will increase over time, so `CASE WHEN` will break in the future

Comment: @shA.t I tried that, I returns the latest two quarters, but it gives the order 2 & 3 instead of 1 & 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH ordered 
     AS (SELECT qcd_outlet_code, 
                qcd_year, 
                qcd_quarter, 
                qcd_credit, 
                Row_number() 
                  over ( 
                    PARTITION BY qcd_outlet_code 
                    ORDER BY qcd_outlet_code, qcd_year DESC, qcd_quarter DESC) 
                AS rn 
         FROM   QTR_CREDIT_DATA) 
SELECT d.qcd_outlet_code    AS "Outlet_Code:string", 
       d.qcd_quarter 
       ||' ' 
       ||d.qcd_year         AS "MCT_quarter:string", 
       Nvl(d.qcd_credit, 0) AS "MCT_Total_Credits_Earned", 
       Row_number() 
                  over ( 
                    PARTITION BY qcd_outlet_code 
                    ORDER BY qcd_outlet_code, qcd_year, qcd_quarter)
                           AS "Display_Order:string" 
FROM   ordered d 
WHERE  rn <= 2;
```

Comment: Adding `over partition` to the main query, as well as adding `desc` to the CTE partition clause did the trick. Thanks a lot